# Good server architecture for publishing/subscribing in Rust

Tags: rust, async-await, concurrency, publish-subscribe, ownership

I'm trying to implement a server in Rust and I wonder if I'm missing something to make it less complex. The simplification of my project would be that I want to have different clients connected to a server, each receiving what the others publish in real time.

I want to do this in an async runtime (tokio atm). Each client has its stream, which I divide into a stream and a sink:

```
let (split_sink, split_stream) = stream.split();
```

I just want to connect each split_stream into every other split_sink in the simplest way possible.

I've been able to solve this by using Arc and Mutex.

- Since the list of subscribers in each publisher needs to be accessed both from the task that handles the connection of new clients and from the task that handles the published messages of that publisher, I wrap them in Arc and Mutex.
- Since each subscriber needs to be accessed from multiple publishers, I wrap them in Arc and Mutex.

This leaves me with something like this:

```
pub struct Publisher {
    subscribers: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Arc<Mutex<Subscriber>>>>>,
    ...
}

impl Publisher {
    ...
    pub async fn add(&self, subscriber: Arc<Mutex<Subscriber>>) {
        self.subscribers.lock().await.push(subscriber);
    }
    ...
    async fn forward_message(
        message: Message,
        subscribers: &Arc<Mutex<Vec<Arc<Mutex<Subscriber>>>>>,
    ) {
        for subscriber in subscribers.lock().await.iter() {
            let mut subscriber = subscriber.lock().await;
            subscriber.split_sink.send(message.clone()).await.unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Rust and this looks bad to me, overly complex. Are there any simplifications I can make? Something like better datastructures for concurrency or a different architecture? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like this project is a good candidate for https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/.

Comment: @SirDarius thanks, I think I'll use the MPSC from Tokio. It looks similar to the crossbeam channel and Tokio is already a dependency in my project. I might look into this in the future if I run into performance problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tokio::sync::broadcast`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html) seems to match your requirements pretty well.

If you want to implement it yourself, options for communication between threads include:

- [`std::sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/index.html): atomics, synchronization objects, etc.
- [`tokio::sync`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/index.html): async-compatible versions of synchronization objects, various kinds of channels, etc.
- [`futures_core::stream`](https://docs.rs/futures-core/latest/futures_core/stream/index.html)/[`tokio_stream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/): like `Iterator` but async

Comment: In the future I'll need to have different subscribers for each publisher, so I don't think I'll use broadcast. The tokio::sync mpsc looks like a great match, thank you! I don't have much experience with multithreading but this looks promising.